# Why is IValueConverter not called for DataGrid autogenerated Column

Tags: wpf, datagrid, ivalueconverter

In an autogenerated datagrid column, I want to replace a certain value (-1) with blank.

I created an IValueConverter:

```
<ValueConversion(GetType(DataRowView), GetType(String))>
Public Class UsageConversion
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
        Dim model As ProgModel = DirectCast(value, ProgModel)
        If model.Usage = -1 Then
            Return ""
        Else
            Return model.Usage.ToString
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

And bound it into the OnAutoGeneratingColumn method:

```
        Dim dgtc As DataGridTextColumn = TryCast(e.Column, DataGridTextColumn)
        If dgtc IsNot Nothing Then 
                Dim UsageBinding = New Binding()
                UsageBinding.Converter = New UsageConversion
                Dim tbStyle As New Style
                tbStyle.TargetType = GetType(TextBlock)
                tbStyle.Setters.Add(New Setter(TextBlock.TextProperty, UsageBinding))
                dgtc.ElementStyle = tbStyle
        End If
```

The OnAutoGeneratingColumn runs well, but the Convert code does not run - setting a breakpoint in it shows it is never called.

Any ideas why?

I am using .Net 4.0

Thanks!

Comment: Does a breakpoint in your `OnAutoGeneratingColumn` handler get hit?

Comment: Yes, a breakpoint shows that the code I posted from OnAutoGeneratingColumn does run, and that dgtc.ElementStyle setters includes a setter with Property = Text

Comment: Have you tried setting `UsageBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;`? Maybe it *is* working, but just not *when* expected?

Comment: @Sheridan, tried this now, no change.  I mean the Converter to be called when the data is loaded into the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Guess you have to set UsageBinding.Path property

Binding.Path property it not set so you column it binded to nothing 
and that is why no value comes to Converter

try this

```
Dim UsageBinding = New Binding(e.PropertyName)
UsageBinding.Converter = New UsageConversion
dgtc.Binding=UsageBinding
```

Comment: Thanks.  This did not make any difference.

Comment: I guess you dont need style there Just bind your column to data via Converter

Comment: My comment about this not making a difference was for the suggestion before the edit.  As it stands now - this is the correct answer - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're trying to set this `Binding` on the `ElementStyle`... surely, you just want to set that `Binding` on the whole column:

```
    Dim dgtc As DataGridTextColumn = TryCast(e.Column, DataGridTextColumn)
    If dgtc IsNot Nothing Then 
            Dim UsageBinding = New Binding()
            UsageBinding.Converter = New UsageConversion
            dgtc.Binding = UsageBinding
```

Comment: Oh... just beaten to it. If this is the solution, please award the accepted answer to @potehin143.

Comment: As @potehin143 only posted a comment, I can just +1 it.  Tanks anyway - you were right on the mark.

Comment: and BTW, no need for "YourPropertyName". Dim UsageBinding = New Binding() works just fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks for getting back to me... I'll update my example accordingly.